# How does the use of disintegration theorem make sense here?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, polish-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Polish spaces and $\mathcal P(X)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$.

- Fix $\mu\in \mathcal P(X), \nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$. Let $\gamma \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$, i.e., $\gamma \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ whose marginal on $X$ is $\mu$ and that on $Y$ is $\nu$.
- Let $c:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ and $\varphi:X \to \mathbb R \cup\{-\infty\}$ be measurable. Let $\psi:Y \to \mathbb R \cup\{-\infty\}$ which is **not** necessarily measurable.
- We assume $\varphi (x) + \psi (y) = c(x, y)$ for $\gamma$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. This means there is a Borel subset $S$ of $X \times Y$ such that $\gamma (S) = 1$, $\varphi (x), \psi(y) \neq \pm\infty$, and $\varphi (x) + \psi (y) = c(x, y)$ for all $(x, y) \in S$.

At page 84 of Villani's *Optimal Transport: Old and New*, the author constructs a measurable $\psi': Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ such that $\psi (y) = \psi' (y)$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$ as follows.

> The measurability of $\psi$ is subtle also, and at the present level of generality it is not clear that this function is really Borel measurable. However, it can be modified on a $\nu$-negligible set so as to become measurable. Indeed, $\varphi (x) + \psi (y) = c(x, y)$ for $\gamma$-almost surely, so if one disintegrates $\gamma (\mathrm dx, \mathrm dy)$ as $\gamma(\mathrm d x | y) \nu(\mathrm d y)$, then $\psi(y)$ will coincide, $\nu(\mathrm d y)$-almost surely, with the Borel function
> $$
> \psi'(y):=\int_{X}[c(x, y) - \varphi (x)] \gamma(\mathrm d x | y).
> $$

The disintegration theorem applies when the integrand is either non-negative measurable or bounded measurable. I could not see how the map
$$
(x, y) \mapsto c(x, y) - \varphi (x)
$$
qualifies here. Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Comment: I think you might mistake the disintegration theorem for a different result. The simplest version, sufficient for this case, says that for $X$, $Y$ Polish and $\gamma\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)$, there is a measurable function $\rho:X\to \Delta(Y)$ such that for $F\subseteq X\times Y$ Borel one has $\gamma(F)=\int\int 1_F(x,y)~\mathrm d\rho_x(y)~\mathrm d\mu(x)$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I understand that disintegration theorem leads to the collection $\{\gamma(\mathrm d x | y) | y \in Y \}$. But i don't get how the map $\psi'$ is well-defined and measurable. Could you please explain it?

Comment: It seems what you want to know is why the integrals are well-defined. This does not follow from the part you quote; it follows from the assumption made that $c\geq a+b$ with $a$ $\mu$-integrable and $b$ $\nu$-integrable.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I assume $c:X \times Y \to [0, \infty)$, so we can pick $a \equiv 0$ and $b \equiv 0$ and that requirement is trivially satisfied. Could you explain how the integral is well-defined and measurable? [...]

Comment: [...]  Let $f(x, y) := c(x, y) - \varphi (x)$. Then $f$ is measurable. I think the author deduces that $y \mapsto \int f(x,y) \gamma(\mathrm d x | y)$ is measurable from claim 1. of this version of [disintegration theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563738/disintegration-theorem-how-do-the-authors-prove-that-mu-y-is-supported-on?rq=1). However, we don't know if $f$ is bounded or integrable... This confuses me.

Comment: That is the standard machinery of going from indicator functions to simple functions to increasing limits of simple functions, which works with all nonnegative functions. And this still works if the integral is infinite.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker So you meant $\psi'$ is well-defined and measurable even if $f$ is just measurable (in this case)?

Comment: If all your functions are nonnegative, yes.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker If $f$ is non-negative, then [disintegration theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Disintegration_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) still holds, but we don't know if $f$ is non-negative...

Comment: In Villani's book, the value of the function at $y$ is defined to be the integral of$\psi(x)+c(x,y)$ with respect to the value of the disintegration at $y$. Villani assumes both $c$ to be (and shows this is wlog under his assumptions) nonnegative and $\psi$ to be integrable. Since you you use different notation, that is not easy to square with your question.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I'm sorry for the different notations. I'm reading the proof of *Theorem 5.10 (ii)*, the part $(b) \implies (c)$. I could not find where Villani assumes $\psi$ (in his notation) is integrable. Could you elaborate on where you find this essential assumption?

Comment: Sorry, I looked again and it is less clear to me how Villani does it. But the problem should be avoidable as long as either the positive or negative part of $\varphi$ is integrable, only $\infty-\infty$-problems are troublesome.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I have a closely related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579160/how-can-varphic-be-written-as-varphic-lim-ell-rightarrow-infty) about the measurability of $\varphi^c$. Please have a look at it.